# How to express this quotient in another way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's suppose we have the following quotient:
$$\frac{a+b}{c+d}$$
Is there a way to express the quotient in a form like this?:
$$\frac{a}{c} + expression + \frac{b}{d}$$
Where $expression$ can be any expression, the only condition is the presence of $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the expression be

$$ - \frac{a}{c} + \frac{a+b}{c+d} - \frac{b}{d}$$

Comment: Thanks!, may i know how did you arrived to the result?

Comment: well, $\frac{a}{c} - \frac{a}{c} = 0$ and $\frac{b}{d} - \frac{b}{d} = 0$. I just add and subtract the same term.

Answer (score 0):

There's the trivial answer: $$\frac{a+b}{c+d} -\frac{a}{c} - \frac b d$$

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the expression cannot be a function of only $\frac ac$ and $\frac bd$, because the mediant operation $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ is not invariant with respect to equivalent fractions. For example, generally we have $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\neq\frac{a+2b}{c+2d}$, even though $\frac{b}{d}=\frac{2b}{2d}$.

You can, trivially, express the difference in terms of all four numbers $a,b,c,d$. See the other answers for that approach.